# how i can get correct time using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

For my website am working with phpmyadmin as a back end. i have number of queries written on mysql in my programs.

Queries are working fine.

```
> But the problem is i am getting previous date upto 12.30PM.
```

It is a problem with mysql server. It is delay with 12 hours 32 minutes according to my time.

To display today's date before 12:30 Pm, i have to change all code  How i can solve this without changing.

Comment: How about you set the correct time on your server?

Answer (score 0):

its simple,just use `now()` method,its is a native mysql method, it will gives you correct time stamp.
guess you want to insert a time into table then use like

```
INSERT INTO X(time) VALUES (NOW());
```

Comment: is it possible to change time on server?

Comment: [Here] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time-zone-support.html)is the link about global time set in mysql server